# How to retrieve contact number from phonebook in android?

Tags: java, android

/*This is my override function. It works fine when I just retrieve names from the phone book. But the app crashes the moment i try to retrieve a contact number.*/

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case (1) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
                c.close();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error logcat.

Comment: What error are you getting? You should post your entire error

Comment: I am getting runtime errors:

Comment: There must be error displayed in your logcat at the bottom. You know where the logcat is, right?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create POJO class.

```
public class ContactEntity {

String name;
String number;
String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

Now, to retrieve contacts.

```
 ArrayList<ContactEntity> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

 contactList = getcontactList();

public ArrayList<ContactEntity> getcontactList() //This Context parameter is nothing but your Activity class's Context
{
    ArrayList<ContactEntity> allContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    Integer contactsCount = cursor.getCount(); // get how many contacts you have in your contacts list
    if (contactsCount > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                //the below cursor will give you details for multiple contacts
                Cursor pCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                // continue till this cursor reaches to all phone numbers which are associated with a contact in the contact list
                while (pCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int phoneType = pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    //String isStarred      = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED));
                    String phoneNo = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    //you will get all phone numbers according to it's type as below switch case.


                    ContactEntity entity = new ContactEntity();
                    entity.setName(contactName);
                    entity.setNumber(phoneNo);
                    allContacts.add(entity);

                    //Log.e will print all contacts according to contact types. Here you go.
                    switch (phoneType) {
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_MOBILE", " " + phoneNo);
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_HOME", " " + phoneNo);
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_WORK", " " + phoneNo);
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                            Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_WORK_MOBILE", " " + phoneNo);
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                            Log.e(contactName + ": TYPE_OTHER", " " + phoneNo);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                pCursor.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
    return allContacts;
}
```

Comment: I keep on getting an error on this line -- getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); would you know why?

Comment: Have you provided permissions for contacts in manifest file  .. @Gerard Grundy

Comment: Can you please elaborate clearly what error do you get .. to have an exact reason. Because this code is running perfectly ..

Comment: I figured out what was going on. I am running on gradle 25 and just adding the permissions in the Manifest doesn't automatically ask for the request.  After I added a request manager then everything works here.  Thanks for your help.  This article too was awesome for setting up the request.  https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem, but I have a code for getting phone number you can have a try:

```
public String getPhone(Context context, String contactID) {
        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
        Cursor phoneCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactID}, null);
        String phoneNo = "";
        if(phoneCursor != null) {
            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
            }
            phoneCursor.close();
        }
        return phoneNo;
    }
```